# Why is this discrete encoding not calculating properly? Am i missing something?

Tags: python, math, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to encode some factors into a discrete number, and then reverse engineering the discrete number back into its factors - but once i add enough factors, the reverse process doesn't show the right numbers.

```
a = 3
b = 13
c = 7
d = 8
e = 3
f = 2

state = (((((b)*20+c)*10+d)*10+e)*5+f)*5
# If i add "a*4" to the front of the line (as shown in this line below), A and B is no longer showing correct

state = ((((((a)*4+b)*20+c)*10+d)*10+e)*5+f)*5

print(state)

print("f:", state // 5 % 5)
state = state // 5
print(state)

print("e:", state // 5 % 5)
state = state // 5
print(state)

print("d:", state // 10 % 10)
state = state // 10
print(state)

print("c:", state // 10 % 10)
state = state // 10
print(state)

print("b:", state // 20 % 20)
state = state // 20
print(state)

print("a:", state // 4 % 4)
state = state // 4
print(state)
```

Comment: Of course it's not showing properly - you're hardcoding the transitions from F to E to D to etc. If you change the starting `state` but then don't change the transitions below, what *was* the right output will change and thus will no longer be the right output.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand - what part am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do something which is impossible. If you define

```
def make_state(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    return ((((((a)*4+b)*20+c)*10+d)*10+e)*5+f)*5
```

Then both `make_state(3,13,7,8,3,2)` and `make_state(4,9,7,8,3,2)` evaluate to the same state (1269585). It is thus impossible to start with 1269585 and decode that number back into the original vector. `make_state()` is not one-to-one. It loses information. The smaller calculation `state = (((((b)*20+c)*10+d)*10+e)*5+f)*5` also loses information (at least without severe restrictions on the vectors being recorded). In general, for any integer `x`, the function `f(a,b): return ax+b` will fail to be one-to-one, so unless I am missing something this entire approach to coding a sequence of numbers is a nonstarter.

On the other hand, if there are known upper bounds to the numbers, then you can do something similar. For example, if `a,b,c,d,e,f` are non-negative integers each less than `4,20,10,10,5,5` respectively, then the function

```
def encode(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    return 5*(5*(10*(10*(20*a+b)+c)+d)+e)+f
```

can be inverted. This follows from the [division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm) which states that for any integers `a,b` with `b > 0`, `a` can be *uniquely* written in the form `a = b*q + r` with `0 <= r < b`. In the above function, `f` *in that range* can be uniquely recovered upon division by `5`, as can be the part in the `()` in `5*( ... ) + f`. From thence you can recover `e`, etc. A series of 5 `divmods` will suffice. Note that the bound on `a` doesn't enter into the calculation.

To decode:

```
def decode(n):
    q,f = divmod(n,5)
    q,e = divmod(q,5)
    q,d = divmod(q,10)
    q,c = divmod(q,10)
    a,b = divmod(q,20)
    return a,b,c,d,e,f
```

For example:

```
>>> encode(3,13,7,8,3,2)
184467
>>> decode(184467)
(3, 13, 7, 8, 3, 2)
```

More generally:

```
def encode(numbers, choices):
    #0 <= numbers[i] < choices[i] for all i
    n = numbers[0]
    for x,y in zip(numbers[1:],choices[1:]):
        n = n*y + x
    return n

def decode(n,choices):
    numbers = []
    for d in choices[:0:-1]:
        n,r = divmod(n,d)
        numbers.append(r)
    numbers.append(n)
    return numbers[::-1]
```

works as follows:

```
>>> encode([3,13,7,8,3,2],[4,20,10,10,5,5])
184467
>>> decode(184467,[4,20,10,10,5,5])
[3, 13, 7, 8, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. If you take a look at this:
https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/taxi.py
The author is using the same method in "encode" and "decode". - But is the entire approach flawed? - He seems to be able to use it discreet as intended.

Comment: @skywalkerdk The [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) is a good way to encode vectors of numbers (given an upper bound to them) as a single number. See [the Wikipedia article on Godel numbering of sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering_for_sequences) for this and other approaches

Comment: @skywalkerdk Functions which fail to be one-to-one can nevertheless be one-to-one on certain *subsets* of inputs. Whether or not that approach is flawed depends heavily on the assumptions behind the numbers being encoded. As a general coding approach of integer vectors it is flawed, but it *might* be okay when restricted to the intended vectors.

Comment: @skywalkerdk That github code is fine. Given the ranges in the numbers (given in the comment), unique decodability follows from the division algorithm. I'll edit the question to explain.

Comment: I can see you are way ahead of me on the math - I have to admit i am kind of clueless on the heavy calculations.  What i am looking for are these options:
`7 options x 100 options x 4 options x 20 options x 10 options x 10 options x 5 options x 5 options`  Actual values would be something like these (I don't know how to write it mathematically correct):  `3 of 7 + 43 of 100 + 2 of 4 + 13 of 20 + 3 of 10 + 6 of 10 + 2 of 5 + 4 of 5`  Is something like this possible to encode uniquely? (and one-to-one reversible?)

Comment: You wrote: _"For example, if a,b,c,d,e,f are non-negative integers each less than 4,20,10,10,5,5 respectively, then the function_

`def encode(a,b,c,d,e):
    return 5*(5*(10*(10*(20*a+b)+c)+d)+e)+f`  

How do you set the max-value "4" when defining the algorithm?
Shouldn't **f** also be included in the _def_?

Comment: Wow - Nice work there.

Though, i'm getting an error:
`TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`
At the line: `n, r = divmod(n[0], d)`

Comment: I think i fixed it. I think your decode should include this:

`n = n[0]`

prior to the loop: `for d in choices...`

Comment: @skywalkerdk You decode a number, not a list. The code works as is.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I see it now.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out John. This was really helpful!